# c# change framework error

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, compilation

I am running Visual Studio 2010.
I just change the frame work of my project from 4.0 to 3.5. I removed the reference Microsoft.Framework that it asked me to remove then tried to compile. I now get the error:

> Error 1   Could not load file or
>   assembly 'System.Drawing,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified. Line
>   123, position
>   5.    C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\\\Properties\Resources.resx   123 5

I know that it is referring to code in my resources.resx file:

```
<resheader name="reader">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="writer">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <assembly alias="System.Windows.Forms" name="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <data name="pix-300x300" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\pix-300x300.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
  <data name="pix2" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\pix2.jpg;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
  <data name="pix4" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\pix4.jpg;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
  <data name="pix3" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>..\pix3.jpg;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>
  </data>
```

How would i correct this now that my framework is 3.5?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I have some bug, but project initialy created for .net 2.0   Before it works, but after some visual studio updates it breaks. Is System.Drawing 4.0 exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try regenerating the file by right-clicking the .resx file and choosing 'Run Custom Tool' from the context menu.

Edit: before you do this, change the Access Modifier or add a new value to force a regeneration.

Another edit: See [Downgrade an application from .net 4.0 to 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181813/downgrade-an-application-from-net-4-0-to-3-5/3181835#3181835) for another possibility

Comment: I still get the same error when i do that. Nothing seems to have changed in my code.

Comment: Change the Access Modifier or add a new value to force a regeneration

Comment: I went into the resrouces.resx file and changed the access modifier from internal to public and pressed F5. Then i tried to run the custom tool again. No luck

Comment: I added useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true to my startup folder but im still getting the error.

Comment: I solved the issue. Had to change all Version=4.0.0.0 to  Version=2.0.0.0 and added useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true to my startup

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a [Visual Studio bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532584/error-when-compiling-resx-file-seems-related-to-beta2-bug-5252020#) that caused me a similar problem. I used this workaround to solve it:

> A fix that SEEMS to work is to
>   manually alter one character in the
>   image stream EVERY TIME the
>   usercontrol or form is edited in the
>   designer
>
> ```
> <data name="icons_20.ImageStream" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">
>     <value>
>      AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAFdTeXN0ZW0uV2luZG93cy5Gb3JtcywgVmVyc2lvbj00LjAuMC4w
> ```
>
> Change to
>
> ```
>      AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAFdTeXN0ZW0uV2luZG93cy5Gb3JtcywgVmVyc2lvbj0yLjAuMC4w
> ```
>
> That is `00LjAuMC4w` back to `0yLjAuMC4w` at the end of the line (`00`
>   back to `0y`)

But I have to fix that every time I change something in that form.

Comment: Im not seeing where i would make that change. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: In my case, clicking on the error brought me straight to that line. I just changed a `j00` to `j0y`.

Comment: this is where the error brings me "<value>..\malware2.jpg;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a</value>"

Comment: I have to run to a meeting. Ill be back in an hour. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: I solved the issue. Had to change all Version=4.0.0.0 to  Version=2.0.0.0 and added useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true to my startup

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about this, but since the other answers didn't help, try this. The `Version=4.0.0.0` in your file is telling the compiler to use .net 4.0 assemblies. Try changing them to `Version=3.5.0.0` or `Version=2.0.0.0` and see if that solves it.

Comment: Thank you. I solved the issue. Had to change all Version=4.0.0.0 to  Version=2.0.0.0 and added useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true to my startup

Answer (score 0):

Having this problem for a long time, i lost hope that microsoft fix this bug ever. Then i begin use manual written code for handle pictures contains in resources:

```
string resource = "Company.Namespace.Resources.picture.gif";
pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
.GetManifestResourceStream(resource));
```

Dot forget to set property "Build action" of picture.gif to "Embeded resource"