# Crystal Reports downgrade from .NET 4.0 to .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, crystal-reports

I've made some crystal reports in Visual studios 2010 using .NET framework 4.0. Framework 4.0 demands SP3 on windows XP which does not suite to my client. Now I am forced to downgrade to Framework 3.5 and most probably using Visual Studios 2008.

Can someone Guide how this downgrade can be performed efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this question, it might help you:

[c# change framework error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994216/c-change-framework-error)

"You can try regenerating the file by right-clicking the .resx file and choosing 'Run Custom Tool' from the context menu."

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with Visual Studio 2010 and use Project Properties Application Target Framework 3.5. If you are lucky there is not much to change besides removing the reference to Microsoft.CSharp...

Comment: I've done that but having the error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral..."

Comment: And also, I've upgraded the project from VS 2008 to VS 2010. And currently there is no Microsoft.CSharp reference in the project

Comment: You need to add a reference to System.Drawing.dll.

Comment: If you are not sure where to find it, create a new Windows Forms App, downgrade it to 3.5 and check then the references - it will contain System.Drawing...

Comment: I've added the System.Drawing but the error still exists. is it due to crystal reports. May be the version stick to use .NET 4.0. in Resources.resx file, versions are still 4.0.0.0.